# How to pass an object to a jquery function?

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I have a custom dialog box that has to be displayed in multiple places and I would like to minimize the code multiplication.

```
<p:dialog id="basicDialog" dynamic="true" header="Test Page Survey" widgetVar="surveyPanel"
          showEffect="slide"  hideEffect="drop"  visible="false" modal="true" closable="false"
          onShow="somecondition()">
    <h:form id="surveyForm" styleClass="wizard-panel" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        ...
        ...

       <div id="saveCancelDiv" class="navigation-panel">
            <p:commandButton id="btnCancelSurvey"
                             value="Cancel"
                             onclick="someJS.cancelOrderBalloonShowSurvey(); return false;"
                             type="button"
                             styleClass="cancel-button"/>
            <p:commandButton id="btnContinue"
                             value="Continue"
                             style="float:right;"
                             oncomplete="someJS.handleDialogSubmit(xhr, status, args);"
                             actionListener="#{xx.save}"
                             styleClass="continue-button" />
        </div>

    </h:form>
</p:dialog>

<cp:confirmDialog id="cancel-order-confirm-dialog-survey" umb_key="cancel-order-confirm-dialog-survey" position="right bottom" modal="true" style="z-index: 2000;">

    <div id="outputPanel" class="alert-dialog" >
        Do you really want to cancel this order?
        <br/>

        <p:commandButton id="btnCancelOrderYes" value="Yes" onclick="someJS.cancelOrderBalloonYesSurvey(event); return false;" type="button" />
        <p:commandButton id="btnCancelOrderNo" value="No" onclick="someJS.cancelOrderBalloonHideSurvey(event); return false;"  type="button" />

    </div>
</cp:confirmDialog>
```

cancelOrderBalloonShowSurvey(), cancelOrderBalloonYesSurvey() and cancelOrderBalloonHideSurvey() are JS functions that should be used every time someone wants to use this 
custom confirm dialog box. But that is not the case yet.
What I want to do is pass in the 'surveyPanel' dialog to the cancelOrderBalloonYesSurvey(event). I have tried something like this

```
    cancelOrderBalloonYesSurvey(event, surveyPanel) -> this did not work
    cancelOrderBalloonYesSurvey(event, this.surveyPanel) -> this did not work
    cancelOrderBalloonYesSurvey(event, this.parent.surveyPanel) -> this did not work
```

How can I pass in the pointer to surveyPanel, so that surveyPanel can be closed in cancelOrderBalloonYesSurvey() ?

Comment: What is surveyPanel? I don't see a tag with that ID or class.

Comment: It is part of first line of code : widgetVar="surveyPanel"

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would pass the parameter as a string:

```
cancelOrderBalloonYesSurvey(event, 'surveyPanel');
```

And consume the string using the PF function as follows:

```
PF('surveyPanel').close();
```

You could also pass the object this way:

```
cancelOrderBalloonYesSurvey(event, PF('surveyPanel'));
```